# C++ Windows: Handle application external crash into the program

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I have the following function to execute an external program:

```
std::string exec(const char* cmd) {
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("_popen() failed!");
    try {
        while (!feof(pipe)) {
            if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
                result += buffer;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        _pclose(pipe);
        throw;
    }
    _pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

Is it possible to handle crash as an exception in this way(I use dir as an example, it does not crash)?

```
std::ostringstream ossCmd;
ossCmd << "dir";
std::string cmd = ossCmd.str();

try
{
   std::string str = exec(cmd.c_str());
}
catch(...)
{

}
```

I cannot get the exception if the external application ends with the external crash error. Example: "dir has stopped working"

Comment: Because that "has stopped working" is not a C++ exception, but either a fatal error (no, you can't stop it) or a Microsoft specific "Structured Exception". Neither can be caught that simply, and neither can be continued safely.

Comment: Could you clarify if it's the external program that is crashing, or your application? This dramatically changes your question.

Comment: @MaxVollmer: `dir` does not crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are under Windows using Visual C++ you can use [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) to run the external program, and [`GetExitCodeProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the program's exit status.

You cannot catch any exception that occurred inside the other process, but you can check the result of `GetExitCodeProcess` for an exception value. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189(v=vs.85).aspx):

> - The exit value specified in the ExitProcess or TerminateProcess function.
> - The return value from the main or WinMain function of the process.
> - The exception value for an unhandled exception that caused the process to terminate.

Of course, this assumes you have no access to the source of the external program. If you have the external program's source, then you should debug and fix the issue there instead of trying to catch it from outside.

Comment: Since the "program" being invoked is a simple `dir`, I interpret the question as saying the "host" program is what's crashing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then the question should be edited/rephrased. Now people who search for solutions to catching exceptions/crashes in external programs, will end up here.

Comment: Feel free to do so!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an "exception"; it's a crash.

You can't catch a crash.

The way to proceed is to run your program under your *debugger*. It will then provide you with the information you require to find, diagnose and correct the problem.